# How to check multiple Component class types with React PropTypes?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

Assume that I have two components `A` and `B`. Then I have another component which takes one of these two.

**C.js**

```js
import A from './A'
import B from './B'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

function C({ Component }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Cool Component</div>
      <Component />
    </div>
  )
}

C.propTypes = {
  Component: PropTypes.oneOfType([A, B])
}

export default C
```

I have tried the solution above yet it didn't work.

Comment: How do you it for just one, for example, just for component `A`?

Comment: I don't know enough about PropTypes to answer this (I could do it in typescript) but you want to make sure that you are requiring the component class/function itself rather than an *instance* of `A` or `B`.

Comment: At this point writing React with TypeScript seems appealing to me. Yet the overhead is frightening me.